# Passing Data From Javascript-Generated Textboxes to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

long time reader, first time poster.  I am working on a form which uses select boxes to create the number of text boxes a user requires.  The Javascript appears to work just fine, each creates the right number of textboxes.  I become lost in how to get the values from these varying number of textboxes back into PHP for further processing.  I would be grateful for any advice.

Here is my JavaScript (stored as a separate file and called at the start of the page).

```
                        function BuildFormFields($amount)
                        {
                    var
                $container = document.getElementById('FormFields'),
                $item, $field, $i;
                        $container.innerHTML = '';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
                $item = document.createElement('div');
                $item.style.margin = '3px';

                $field = document.createElement('span');
                $field.innerHTML = 'Name of Expert';
                $field.style.marginRight = '10px';
                $item.appendChild($field);

                $field = document.createElement('input');
                $field.name = 'name_expert[' + $i + ']';
                                    $field.type = 'text';
                                $item.appendChild($field);

                $field = document.createElement('span');
                $field.innerHTML = 'Title';
                $field.style.margin = '0px 10px';
                $item.appendChild($field);

                $field = document.createElement('input');
                $field.name = 'expert_title[' + $i + ']';
                $field.type = 'text';
                $item.appendChild($field);

                                    $field = document.createElement('span');
                $field.innerHTML = 'Organization';
                $field.style.margin = '0px 10px';
                $item.appendChild($field);

                $field = document.createElement('input');
                $field.name = 'organization[' + $i + ']';
                $field.type = 'text';
                $item.appendChild($field);

                $container.appendChild($item);
                    }
                        }



        function BuildFormFields2($amount2)
        {
        var
                $container2 = document.getElementById('FormFields2'),
                $item2, $field2, $i2;

            $container2.innerHTML = '';
            for ($i2 = 0; $i2 < $amount2; $i2++) {
                $item2 = document.createElement('div');
                $item2.style.margin = '3px';

                $field2 = document.createElement('span');
                $field2.innerHTML = 'Competency';
                $field2.style.marginRight = '10px';
                $item2.appendChild($field2);

                $field2 = document.createElement('input');
                $field2.name = 'competency[' + $i2 + ']';
                $field2.type = 'text';
                $item2.appendChild($field2);

                $field2 = document.createElement('span');
                $field2.innerHTML = 'Number of Skills';
                $field2.style.margin = '0px 10px';
                $item2.appendChild($field2);

                $field2 = document.createElement('input');
                $field2.name = 'num_skills[' + $i2 + ']';
                $field2.type = 'text';
                $item2.appendChild($field2);

                $container2.appendChild($item2);
                     }
                                     }
                    function BuildFormFields3($amount3)
        {
            var
                $container3 = document.getElementById('FormFields3'),
                $item3, $field3, $i3;

            $container3.innerHTML = '';
            for ($i3 = 0; $i3 < $amount3; $i3++) {
                $item3 = document.createElement('div');
                $item3.style.margin = '3px';

                $field3 = document.createElement('span');
                $field3.innerHTML = 'Position';
                $field3.style.marginRight = '10px';
                $item3.appendChild($field3);

                $field3 = document.createElement('input');
                $field3.name = 'position[' + $i3 + ']';
                $field3.type = 'text';
                $item3.appendChild($field3);



                $container3.appendChild($item3);
            }

                           }
```

And here is an example of one of the "p" blocks I am currently using for the select boxes:

```
    <p><strong>Number of Experts that Participated: </strong><select  name="number_experts" onchange="BuildFormFields(parseInt(this.value, 10));">
    <option value=0>-- Skip for Now --</option>
    <?php 
    for ($range = 1; $range <= 10; $range++) 
    {
    echo '<option value=' . $range . '>' . $range . '</option>'; 
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <div id="FormFields" style="margin: 20px 0px;"></div>
    </p>
```

Comment: I thank all for your responses so far.  I would just like to point out that the HTML/PHP portion already has a the proper form tags to operate.  My issue is taking all of those textboxes created by the Javascript and getting those values into variables on the PHP side after clicking the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure your inputs are wrapped in a form tag and using the FormData object is probably the best way.

```
function sendDetails() {
    var fData = new FormData(document.getElementById('MyFormID'));
    $.post('/your/submission/url.php', fData, function (data) {
        // Your success script here
    });
}
$('someButton').bind('click', sendDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<p><strong>Number of Experts that Participated: </strong><select  name="number_experts" onchange="BuildFormFields(parseInt(this.value, 10));">
    <option value=0>-- Skip for Now --</option>
    <?php 
    for ($range = 1; $range <= 10; $range++) 
    {
    echo '<option value=' . $range . '>' . $range . '</option>'; 
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <form action="action.php" method="post">
    <div id="FormFields" style="margin: 20px 0px;"></div>
    <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
    </p>
```

In action.php, you can use something like

```
<?php echo $_POST["thefieldnamefromyourhtml"]; ?>
```

Comment: I appreciate the fast response.  I have the proper form tags in the php script already, I was just showing you one select box block to demonstrate what I had.